# django queryset use .values for the foreign key field

Tags: django, orm, django-queryset

I have a model which the `creator` field is a forign key from `user` table :

CompanyTemplateMessage

```
class CompanyTemplateMessage(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True, null=True)
    subject = models.CharField(max_length=256)
    company = models.ForeignKey('Company', on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='company_template')
    text = models.TextField()
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True, blank=True, null=True)
    creator = models.ForeignKey(
        'user.User',
        null=True,
        blank=True,
        on_delete=models.SET_NULL,
        related_name='user_template_message',
    )
```

DefaultTemplateMessage : (I want to combine this table with previus one and return them in aqueryset)

```
class DefaultTemplateMessage(models.Model):
    
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True, null=True)
    subject = models.CharField(max_length=256)
    text = models.TextField()
    html = models.TextField()
```

User:

```
class User(AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin):

    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_staff = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    email = models.EmailField(max_length=255, unique=True)
    phone = PhoneNumberField(unique=True, null=True, blank=True)
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True, blank=True)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True, blank=True)
    join_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    
    companies = models.ManyToManyField(
        'company.Company',
        related_name='members',
        blank=True,
    )


    USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'

    def __str__(self):
        return self.email
```

i want to combine this queryset with other queryset and use `union` , so i have to use `values()` to choose same fields of these quesrysets to be able to union

i use this queryset and `values()` parameter to determine which field is chosen to show

first queryset which i have problem in it with values():

```
        company_code = self.kwargs.get('company_code')
        company_template_objs = CompanyTemplateMessage.objects.filter(company__code=company_code).values(
            'name', 'created_at', 'creator')
```

second queryset and union it with first one:

```
    def get_queryset(self):
        company_code = self.kwargs.get('company_code')
        company_template_objs = CompanyTemplateMessage.objects.filter(company__code=company_code).values('name', 'type', 'subject', 'text', 'creator')
        default_template_objs = DefaultTemplateMessage.objects.all().values(
            'name', 'type', 'subject', 'text').annotate(
            creator=Value(4, output_field=IntegerField()))
        template_objs = company_template_objs.union(default_template_objs)
        return template_objs
```

if i consider first queryset byitself without second quesryset and `union` , when i dont use `values()` in it, it works properly and shows the `creator` field. but when i choose `creator` in the fields , it shows this error :

```
'int' object has no attribute 'pk'
```

and when i use something else like :  `'creator__email'` or `'creator__id'` the creator field returns null value while it is filled by a user

what should i use for this field to show the user value ?

Comment: *don't* use `.values(...)`: https://www.django-antipatterns.com/antipattern/over-use-of-values.html

Comment: I have to use value() becouse i want to combine two querysets by union and they should have same fields to be able to union

Comment: union with *what*? Please share the *full* problem...

Comment: I edited my question and add it , i wanted to simplify the question so i didnt talk about union

Comment: how does the `DefaultTemplateMessage` looks like?

Answer (score 0):

> what should i use for this field to show the user value ?

*don't* use `.values()`. Indeed, Django can perfectly follow `ForeignKey`s, by using `.values()` it will return a `QuerySet` of dictionaries, which are less "richt" objects that model instances. You can use [**`.select_related(…)`** <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/models/querysets/#prefetch-related) to efficiently also fetch the `creator` data in the same query, although that is not necessary from a *functional* perspective:

```
def get_queryset(self):
    return CompanyTemplateMessage.objects.filter(
        company__code=self.kwargs['company_code']
    ).select_related('creator')
```

---

> **Note**: It is normally better to make use of the [**`settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL`** <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.comen/stable/ref/settings/#std:setting-AUTH_USER_MODEL) to refer to the user model, than to use the [**`User`** model <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.comen/stable/ref/contrib/auth/#django.contrib.auth.models.User) directly. For more information you can see the [*referencing the `User` model* section of the documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/topics/auth/customizing/#referencing-the-user-model).